# Como ler a propriedade 'Titulo' da Aba Detalhes de um arquivo FONT TRUE TYPE?

Tags: delphi

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno aplicativo que lê um .MDB, da qual existem nomes de fonte.
Então verifico se estas fontes estão instaladas , se não , instalo-as .Mas tenho que saber o nome de Titulo da Fonte que fica dentro da tela de propriedades/Datalhes para saber com exatidão a fonte a ser inserida. Uma vez que tenho nome do arquivo = "x.ttf" e nome na aba detalhes "x.ttf" , ai ok funciona bem , mas quando tenho "x.ttf" = nome do arquivo e "xx.ttf"
na propriedade ai dá tudo errado.

Comment: Será que é isso? http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=171299 (veja a sugestão do Chris).

Answer (score 2):

Vale responder para termos o histórico e caso no futuro alguém precise.

A forma mais simples é instalar, verificar e desinstalar, assim tendo acesso ao nome da fonte. 
Segue rotina:

```pascal
Function NomedaFonte(Font: WideString):WideString;
type
  TGetFontResourceInfoW = function(Name: PWideChar; var BufSize: Cardinal;
    Buffer: pointer; InfoType: Cardinal): LongBool; stdcall;
var
  naf, k, y: integer;
  gfri: TGetFontResourceInfoW;
  lf: array of TLogFontW;
  lfsz: Cardinal;
  hfnt: HFONT;
  Nome: WideString;
begin
  gfri := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('gdi32.dll'), 'GetFontResourceInfoW');
  if @gfri = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('GetFontResourceInfoW in gdi32.dll não funciona.');
  if LowerCase(ExtractFileExt(Font)) = '.pfm' then
    Font := Font + '|' + ChangeFileExt(Font, '.pfb');
  naf := AddFontResourceW(PWideChar(Font)); //carrega fonte
  try
    if naf > 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(lf, naf);
      lfsz := naf * SizeOf(TLogFontW);
      if not gfri(PWideChar(Font), lfsz, @lf[0], 2) then
        raise Exception.Create('GetFontResourceInfoW não pode ser chamado.');
      y := 0;
      naf := lfsz div SizeOf(TLogFont);
      for k := 0 to naf - 1 do
      begin
        hfnt := CreateFontIndirectW(lf[k]);
        try
          Nome := lf[k].lfFaceName; //Pega nome da fonte
          Result := Nome;
        finally
          DeleteObject(hfnt);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    RemoveFontResourceW(PWideChar(Font)); //Descarrega fonte
  end;
end;
```

[Fonte](http://www.delphipraxis.net/63058-font-dynamisch-laden-ohne-installieren.html)*(em alemão).*